# Unable to mount cgroup

Tags: centos, mount, lxc, cgroups

I've been searching for a solution to this problem but none was working.

I would like to start my LXC container but i need to mount cgroup before.

```
[root@stag-devCentOs ~]# lxc-start -n debianLxc
lxc-start: cgroup is not mounted
lxc-start: failed to spawn '/sbin/init'
lxc-start: cgroup is not mounted
```

I've read that i need to add the followind line to my `/etc/fstab`

```
cgroup                  /sys/fs/cgroup          cgroup  defaults        0 0
```

and then i had to enter `mount /sys/fs/cgroup` or `mount -a`.

I've done everything but i'm still getting this error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup,
    missing codepage or other error
    In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
    dmesg | tail or so
```

I'm using CentOS 5.10 with a 3.2.60-1.el5.elrepo kernel.

Here is what i get when i'm using dmesg | tail:

```
[root@stag-devCentOs ~]# dmesg | tail
Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
br0: no IPv6 routers present
SELinux: initialized (dev autofs, type autofs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev autofs, type autofs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev autofs, type autofs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev mqueue, type mqueue), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev proc, type proc), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev mqueue, type mqueue), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev proc, type proc), uses genfs_contexts
```

If you want to see my `/etc/fstab` content, here it is:

```
LABEL=/                 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
/dev/vglxc/lvhome       /home                   ext3    defaults        1 1
/dev/vglxc/lvopt        /opt                    ext3    defaults        1 1
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
LABEL=SWAP-sda2         swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
cgroup                  /sys/fs/cgroup          cgroup  defaults        0 0
```

I have to keep using LVM with `/home` and `/opt` like this and i need to keep lxc version on 0.6.4.

Do you have any idea on how to solve those issues or maybe explain what is wrong ?

Comment: Please check with `grep "cgroup" /proc/filesystem` if cgroup is supported by your kernel.

Comment: i'm getting `grep: /procfilesystem: No such file or directory` does it mean my kernel isn't compatible with cgroups ? If so how can i use lxc on this system ?

Comment: I meant `grep: /proc/filesystem: No such file or directory`, sorry i forgotten `/` writing my comment.

Comment: Sorry, there is also a typo on my side: it is `/proc/filesystems` with an s at the end.

Comment: It gives me `nodev cgroup`, thanks for answering me sir.

Comment: Good, cgroup is supported by your kernel.